# How to show random auto-rotate data from mysql?

Tags: mysql, random, rotation

I have a small box on my website with wisdom quotes

I wan´t them to appear randomly with a smooth fade, without reloading the page

I´ve found a lot of tutorials but none of them explains how randomly showing
data from mysql (only from xml or with the text hardcoded within the document)

This is my code:

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost", "xxxxxx", "xxxxxx") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db ("xxxxxx") or die(mysql_error());

    $select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `randomtext` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($select)) {
?>              

<div class="wisdom-textbox">
    <p class="font-wisdom">"<?php echo $row ['text']  ?>"</p>
</div>
```

It´s working randomly and change if I refresh - but I need the feature to make it rotate to another random wisdom text from the database within some seconds (a small fade wouldn´t hurt)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot expect MySQL to send data to you until it is asked to.

What you can do is request for new quotes. For that you will have to execute the query again.

In order to execute the query again you have to either poll or use some timer which executes the query.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try JavaScript,
JavaScript Timing Events can really help you here,
i dont really understand what you are trying to do in your website but go to this 
[Link](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)
and mabye that can help you solve your problem.
Good Luck.